# Rails: Rewrite get variables in URL to cleaner style

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to submit a search query get variables as /search/query instead of /search?search=query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Define route in your routes.rb

```
map.search "/search/:search", :controller => "search", :action => "index", :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

restart server and check.

for more info ref [Module ActionController::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)